# Is casting a deque to and from void pointer safe?

Tags: c++, stl

The documentation says that

> unlike vectors, deques are not guaranteed to store all its elements in contiguous storage locations

Does it mean that if I cast a deque to a void * and then back to the original deque I might end up with some random data inside?

Comment: Well it won't work, but not because of pointer safety issues but because a `std::deque` object is *not a pointer* and have no conversion operator to pointer of any kind.

Comment: Besides what @JoachimPileborg already stated, if you refer to the contigouus data block managed by these other container classes mentioned, this pointer also can easily change, as soon the container is manipulated (e.g. with `push_back()`)

Comment: Do you mean the deque object? Or a pointer to it? Or a pointer to its data?

Comment: Just to precise: even though `std::vector` is guaranteed to have contiguous underlying storage, casting `vector` object to pointer will not give you pointer to data. You need to access data via its member functions/operators. Same thing with `deque`.

Comment: @darenn Could you please show us some actual code you're trying to write, which involves such a cast?

Comment: @lethal-guitar it’s just a guess but I would imagine the OP is alluding to the common use of `&vec[0]` to get a pointer to the underlying storage of a `std::vector` – in this case he is right, `static_cast<void*>(&vec[0])` is generally OK (although one can use `vec.data()` for a more legible alternative), but trying the equivalent on a `std::deque`, e.g. `&dq[0]`, doesn’t work; the accepted answer below elaborates: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23650031/298171

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it means that you can't take a deque's first element's address, cast it to a pointer, and then perform pointer arithmetics under the assumption that the rest of the elements are in continuous order:

```
deque<int> d;
//...
int* x = &(d[0]);
int secondElement = x[1]; // illegal 

vector<int> v;
//...
int* x = &(v[0]);
int secondElement = x[1]; // legal
```

You can cast a deque's *address* to a `void*` and cast it back with no worries though.

Comment: This seems like a bad decision on behalf of the c++ language designers. Maybe this could be fixed in future c++ versions? Pointer arithmetic with deque members would be super convenient.

Answer (score 2):

No. That's not what it means. First, you *cannot* cast a `deque` into `void*`. The two will have different sizes, and this will break the object.

What it actually means is that you can do:

```
vector<int> myVec = ...;
int* theBuffer = &myVec[0]; // In C++ 11, you can also do myVec.data() instead
```

And `theBuffer` will be a contiguous segment of memory, so you can pass it to a C function expecting a pointer for example (see below), access it using pointer arithmetic, etc. 
You cannot do this with a `deque`, as it's internal representation doesn't provide such guarantees. Note that this concerns itself with the **data** stored inside a `vector` or `deque`, not with the object itself. In case you'd like to store a pointer to a `deque` in a `void*`, you're free to do so.

```
// Example: A C function
extern "C" void a_c_function(int* data, const size_t num_elements);

// Invoking it on a vector's elements
a_c_function(&myVec[0], myVec.size());
```

Comment: Worth noting that `(void*)&vec[0]` and `(void*)&vec` are *very* different, since the OP's wording suggest he does not realise this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That’s a point that is very much worth making – `&vec[0]` is a very common idiom in C++, such that it’s like slang: if you don’t know what it means, no one will necessarily go out of their way to explain it. In this case, it’s taking the address of the first element of the `std::vector` object; the fact that this element is contiguously aligned in memory in the same physical manner of the analogous C array is _atypical_ of standard-library containers. This useful peculiarity of `std::vector` is the exception and not the rule, in this case, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast structures to pointers. `reinterpret_cast` might compile with some unknown semantics, but it's just asking for brokenness: a `deque` is going to be at least two pointers big, so it can't fit into one pointer.

You can cast a `deque<…> *` to a `void *` and back. This has nothing to do with the contents of the deque, but it's just taking the address of the container object itself.

```
std::deque< int > dq;

void * x = reinterpret_cast< void * >( dq ); // Nonsense.

void * y = static_cast< void * >( & dq ); // Type-erased ptr to object, OK.
std::deque< int > & dqr = * static_cast< std::deque< int > * >( y ); // restore type, OK.
```

The relevant difference between `deque` and `vector` is in their *iterators*: You can use a pointer to an element of a `vector` much  the same as a `vector::iterator` because a vector uses contiguous storage. The only way to navigate through a `deque` is a `deque::iterator`, however.

```
int * vf = & vec.front(); // Ptr to first element
int * velem = vf + 10; // OK if vec has 10 elements.

int * df = & dq.front(); // Ptr to first element
int * delem = df + 10; // Error, although it might work sometimes.
```

Comment: So basically `deque<T>::iterator != deque<T>*`, while  `vector<T>::iterator == vector<T>*`.